# Merge connected lines

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis, connectivity-analysis

I have Road Network which was selected based on some criteria. Below is image representing it. Each beginning and end of Road Segment is marked with cross:

[image]

Selection led to fragmentation of this network. How can I merge (ArcGIS, QGIS) all lines that form consistent continuity, like in image below (colors represent 3 lines which should result after merging). Result of merging – based on below example – should be one layer, with 3 rows, where each row represents grouped lines. Road Network has several attributes, but I am not interested in having them in final, merged output. My goal is to group connected lines:

[image]

I have tried few approaches e.g.: [Using Dissolve and Multipart to Singlepart in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311608/using-dissolve-and-multipart-to-singlepart-in-qgis) [Join / merge lines that touch and intersect in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198317/join-merge-lines-that-touch-and-intersect-in-qgis) and none of it worked.
Dissolve and Multipart-to-Singleparts (QGIS) is not working as expected when 3 lines (or more) are touching each other:

[image]

Comment: Please describe, how `dissolve & multi to singlepart` didn't work. Because that is the place to go for your task.

Comment: Dissolve and Multipart-to-Singleparts (QGIS) is not working as expected when 3 lines (or more) are touching each other. That would be an entrance to roundabout in above example.

Comment: Using the GRASS tool (under QGIS) `v.clean > snap` ? ([documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.clean.html))

Comment: By listing three software environments, you are asking at least two questions, violating the One question per Question policy emphasized by the [Tour]. Please [Edit] this question to focus one one environment, and the exact steps you have taken, and the way in which it didn't work.

Comment: I'd say to just scan down the tools list in QGIS because there is a very obviously named processing tool that would totally split your lines at each intersection.

Comment: @GabrielC. My intention is not splitting but rather opposite.